# jQuery split not a function

Tags: jquery

So, I have following js code:

```
var numbers = pass_tag; 
alert(numbers);
var show_number= numbers.split(",");
```

In the alert I get `123,454,223,422,422'.

However, I get `Uncaught TypeError: numbers.split is not a function`.

I have no idea why it is.

Any suggestions?

THanks

Comment: can you provide full code or `typeof numbers` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** is not a jQuery function. Its a string function in native javascript

And your code is working fine. **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z96j6ywm/)**

```
var numbers = "123,454,223,422,422";
var show_number = numbers.split(",");
alert(show_number.length);
```